# creating standalone node js application installer

Tags: node.js, angularjs, shell, installation, obfuscation

I have already read a lot of links that answer the question.
But I had a **specific doubt**,so here we go!!
Our App uses angular js for UI and node js backend server

This is the way I have planned to execute the objective of creating a standalone applications

1. I would have a shell script run that would minify(not obfuscate -> because in a lot of places, I read obfuscate would create some bugs and minify is a safe enough option) all the JS source files in my application sources
2. Then I would zip them all into one compressed folder
3. I would give the customer the compressed folder and a shell script
4. When the customer runs the shell script,It would decompress the folder and then run all the commands that we manually run to get the app started.

So everytime the customer wants the app , he can just run the shell script(when the files are already extracted, then the decompress step would be skipped.)

Is this approach fine? can I get on with it ?

Comment: Not sure about the skill level of your customers. Target platforms? Can you expect there to be node installed or install it yourself? Auto-open browser? Which browser? You better have a correct defaults set up. Unless you're distributing to technical people and have really good scripting, IMO you'll have problems.

Comment: @panta82. We will be doing the installation ourselves and take care of all the pre requisites. The part where the customer runs the script to get the app started everytime he wants to use the product is the only time he will be running the script and I am sure there would not be a lot of technical expertise needed for that.  what do u think ?

Comment: You create a desktop icon that points to your script. The customer clicks the icon, your script starts up the app in a terminal and opens a browser window. User then uses your app through browser. Correct?

Comment: that is whats intended @panta82

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, your idea can work technically. But it's not very user friendly. The problems I can see off top of my head:

- You need manual installation and maintenance of node executable
- The user gets an ugly console application they have to keep around
- It is not clear how to end application. Close console window? Close browser tab? Browser window?

If I needed to do this, I would go with something like [node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit) or [appjs](http://appjs.com/).

These frameworks allow you to bundle a webkit-based browser with a node executable. You click on an exe, and what you see is a stripped down browser window, with your node.js app powering it silently underneath. No console window, separate browser etc. There's a bridge between the browser part and node, so you don't even need to use ajax to communicate (although nothing is stopping you).

Probably too late to switch at this point, but maybe something to keep in mind in the future.

Comment: i considered node-webkit , but since this is more of a task that has started after the product has released one of its version, I did not know the feasibility of doing that.. because basically we need to integrate the framework right from the start of dev right ?

Comment: It's a normal browser and a normal node.js app underneath, so I suspect anything you can do normally, you can do here (eg. just ignore the memory integration and communicate through ajax / socketio). With caveat that I only tried writing a full-blown desktop app using integration, not converting a web app like you would need to do.

Comment: yes thats exactly what has kept me from taking on any of the aforementioned options. anyways thanks a lot @panta82

Answer (score 6):

You can follow [How to create a Windows (InnoSetup exe) installer (for NodeJS apps)](https://coolaj86.com/articles/how-to-create-an-innosetup-installer.html) that uses inno setup where you can make installer of any node app for windows.

In my case i made an installer that automatically installs node binary on client machine and run server along with my electron angular app.